# How to find the column wise count of updated records

Tags: sql-server

I am new to mssql server database.I have a usecase in which I have to find out the below 2 things:

1. How many records are updated in a particular table in last 1 hour.
2. Column wise count of updated records (which column gets updated and its count in a particular table) in last 1 hour.

Is there any metadata table present in mssql server database in which I can find the above information or any alternate approach to find the same?

Comment: From your phrasing I got the impression that this is not a one-time check but something that would be part of the "system". If this is correct, it would be best to create triggers that would perform a side logging with the needed information.

Comment: There isn't any built-in functionality in `SQL Server` that can provide such information. You will need to build your own information tracking. Most probably is in the `update trigger`. Maybe you can also explain what is the objective of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, your table needs to have UPDATE_DATE column with data type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Update_Date >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE());
```

For the latter case, I advise you to write trigger for logging changed columns. Your log table can be in format of

```
TableName, Column_Name, From, To
```

After that you can query this table and generate your reports.  This is also a good practice because you won't work with production / resource intensive data.

If creating trigger makes sense for you, Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for `COLUMNS_UPDATED` function

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no metadata available for that purpose.
For first requirement, you can create a new field, e.g.

```
Last_Update DATETIME default GETDATE(),
```

And build your query for last hour accourdingly:

```
WHERE Last_Update >= DATEADD(h, -1, GETDATE()
```

Second requirement can be done by combining use of Triggers with a table where you store the results you want to check afterwards.